# HTTP to HTTPS: Sitemap in XSL returns blank page

Tags: php, xml, http, https

I recently migrated a site from HTTP to HTTPS.
I adapted all the codes and everything works fine except the sitemap.

The file `sitemap.php` should return a stylized the URL list, by XSL file.

Everything worked fine in HTTP ... but when moved to HTTPS it returns blank page in Chrome and in IE it returns a no stylized page.

I adapted the urls into the XSL file and into the PHP, from **http** to **https** as well
But the returned page still blank

In the attached screenshot here below, the result of the developer tool on Chrome
[image]

Please here the URL
[www.liciafox.net/sitemap.php](https://www.liciafox.net/sitemap.php)

As I said, this top wroking when I changed the protocol from **http** to **https**

I thank you very much in advance for any suggestion/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. It works. However I don't know if this is the correct way.

The following lines on the `sitemap.php`

```
// Header forming
header("Content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" . "\n";
echo "<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='https://{$url}/sitemap.xsl'?>" . "\n";
echo '<urlset xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"' . "\n";
echo '        xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' . "\n";
echo '        xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">' ."\n";
```

should NOT contain the HTTPS calls to the external site. But it must be only HTTP (except the call to my site)

```
// Header forming
header("Content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" . "\n";
echo "<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='https://{$url}/sitemap.xsl'?>" . "\n";
echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"' . "\n";
echo '        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' . "\n";
echo '        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">' ."\n";
```

Similar way for the headers on the XSL file.
Here below the one didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:html="https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
                xmlns:sitemap="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
                xmlns:xsl="https://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

here below the working one, where the call HTTPS is only on the tag `<html>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
                xmlns:sitemap="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following header in sitemap.php

```
header("Content-type: application/xslt+xml");
```

Comment: if I add that header, the content of the file is not visualized but downloaded as file.
While with the current header: header("Content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8"); it's manages as web page